# Inequality for trace of product of matrices given norms of the matrices

Tags: mathematical-statistics, linear-algebra

I have to show that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|Tr(A_nB_n)| < \infty$. I know that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}||A_n||, \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}||B_n|| < \infty$, where $A_n,B_n$ are $2 \times 2$ random matrices and $ ||X|| = Tr(XX^T)^{1/2}$. Is there any inequality which I can use?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact matrix norm you're using. But can you use the definition of trace directly? I.e. $tr(AB) = \sum_{i=1}^n(AB)_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{A}_{row\,i}^\rm{T} \;  \mathbf{B}_{col\,i} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_j (A)_{ij} (B)_{ji}$

Comment: Then they have finite entries and *obviously* the trace of their product is finite! You can obtain a much stronger result, though, using the [Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality). (Whether the entries are random or not is immaterial.)

Comment: Aha! With the introduction of $\sup_n$, this question finally makes sense. But, again, what is the relevance to this site?

Comment: @whuber it stopped making sense to me! What does $\rm{sup}_n$ mean?

Comment: I have't written $sup$ which is essential here, in order to simplify the notation, however, in the end it became obvious, so I have corrected it. Whuber, could you be more explicit how I can apply the inequality?

Comment: @TooTone: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supremum. Kolibris: the inequality applies directly by viewing the matrices as $4$-dimensional vectors. There's little more to be said; the rest is an application of the definition of supremum.

Comment: @whuber thanks, and thanks for your comment on my (deleted) answer. I was writing it as the question was evolving, and I realized at the end that there wasn't anything productive there.

Comment: @whuber: did you take into account that I have $|Tr(AB)|$, not $|AB|$? If yes, I will think how to do it.

Comment: @whuber Sorry to delete your comment "When you consider each matrix to be just the vector of its coefficients, the norm is the usual Euclidean norm, the trace of the product is the usual inner product, and the inequality is the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, which is equivalent to all cosines being 1 or less in absolute value. The rest is a (very simple) matter of applying the definition of the supremum." Maybe worth reposting as comment/answer?

Comment: @TooTone No problem. Since it sounds like you may have worked out a full solution, I would be grateful if you were to write it up. You (and others) might find that more enlightening than reading mine, which would be brief.  I'm still trying to understand why this question belongs here and not on the Math site, though.

Comment: @whuber will do, have done the back of the envelope sketch now. I love the way you transformed a matrix problem into a vector problem where you could apply C-S. And, I agree, maths might be better. (Although $Tr$ did feature, briefly, in my mathematical statistics course.)

Comment: @TooTone Another approach which you might like is tantamount to the [Holder Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality): from the axiomatic relation $||A_n-B_n||^2\ge 0$ it is straightforward to deduce $2Tr(A_nB_n')\le||A_n||^2+||B_n'||^2$, whence upper bounds $\alpha$ for $\{||A_n||\}$ and $\beta$ for $\{||B_n'||\}$ give an upper bound of $(\alpha^2+\beta^2)/2$ for $\{Tr(A_nB_n)\}$, etc.

Comment: @whuber I have posted the first solution (any mistakes are my own!), and it was instructive, thanks again. I nearly came unstuck at the end where I got an inquality for $AB^T$ not $AB$ but I think it's ok! I might post something on on the math site about $\sup$ applied to matrices in this question as I still don't quite get what it means in plain English... Re your second suggestion, I will take a look and perhaps work through it on paper -- I need to spend some time with my kids (and also work on my software skills, which is what I'm _supposed_ to be doing this weekend:)

Comment: @TooTone The supremum is applied here to sequences of *numbers*, not matrices: the numbers are $Tr(A_nB_n)$, $||A_n||$, and $||B_n||.$ It might help to interpret the question in words as "when there is an upper bound to the norms of the $A_n$ and an upper bound to the norms of the $B_n$, then there is also an upper bound to the norms of the inner products $Tr(A_nB_n)$. So, if all the $A$'s can't get too big and all the $B$'s can't get too big, then there's a (finite) limit to how big all their inner products can get." That should make the truth of this assertion obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @whuber's suggestion, starting with

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
A &=& \left(\begin{array}{rrrr} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right)\\
P &=& \left(\begin{array}{rrrr} p & q \\ r & s \end{array}\right)\\
\end{eqnarray*}_.$$

then the matrix product is

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
AP^T
&=& \left(\begin{array}{rrrr} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right)
    \left(\begin{array}{rrrr} p & r \\ q & s \end{array}\right)\\
&=& \left(\begin{array}{llll} ap+bq & \ldots \\ \ldots & cr + ds \end{array}\right)\\
\end{eqnarray*}_.$$

The norm of a matrix
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
||A||
&=& Tr(AA^T)^{1/2} \\
&=& (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)^{1/2}
\end{eqnarray*}_,$$

is just the Euclidian norm of the matrix treated as a vector of its coefficients $\mathbf{a} = (a, b, c, d)^T$.

The trace of the product
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
Tr(AP^T)
&=& ap + bq + cr + ds
\end{eqnarray*},$$

is just the dot product (inner product) of the matrices treated as vectors of their coefficients.

The [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) states that

$$ |\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}|  \le ||\mathbf{x}||\,||\mathbf{y}||,$$

where the vector norms on the right are Euclidian. This inequality can then be applied to the vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{p}$ of coefficients of the matrices $A$ and $P$.

$$ |Tr(AP^T)| \le ||A||\,||P|| $$

We are given $\sup_{n\in N}||A_n|| < \infty$, and $\sup_{n\in N}||B_n|| < \infty$. Hence

$$ \sup_{n\in N}|Tr(AP^T)| \le \sup_{n\in N}(||A||\,||P||) < \infty, \;\;\mbox{and}$$
$$\sup_{n\in N}|Tr(AP^T)| < \infty .$$

However this is not the form required in the question: it gives an inequality for the trace of the product $AP^T$ rather than $AP$. But $||X||=||X^T||$, which follows from the fact that for Euclidian vector norms $||\mathbf{x}^T|| = ||\mathbf{x}||$, or equivalently, for any matrix $X$, $Tr(XX^T)=Tr(X^TX)$. Setting $B=P^T$ 
$$\sup_{n\in N}|Tr(AB)| < \infty .$$

Comment: I think that you can start with $AP$ instead of $AP^T$. In that case there is no problems with a transpose. whuber: an idea to vectorize matrices is very nice.

Comment: (On the spelling of Cauchy-Schwarz: it's Hermann Amandus Schwarz, rather than Schwartz.)